# Mac OS X Terminal Error: undefined method `grep'

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app

Every time I enter a command, or even just hit enter, in Terminal I get this line below the output:

```
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `grep' for #<String:0x007feea31354b8> (NoMethodError)
```

Odd. Does anyone have any clue as to what this means, and where it's coming from? I'd like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Looks like a problem with a command that runs when `bash` displays the prompt. What are the contents of `$PS1` and `$PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: @chepner This is from .bash_profile: `PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\w \[\033[31m\]\`ruby -e \"print (%x{git branch 2> /dev/null}.grep(/^\*/).first || '').gsub(/^\* (.+)$/, '(\1) ')\"\`\[\033[37m\]\[$(tput sgr0)\]"`.

This is from `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`: update_terminal_cwd;

Comment: The error message is definitely from the Ruby command. You could remove it; delete the backquotes and everything between them. A more general fix would be to modify the Ruby command to avoid the error, but I don't know enough Ruby to explain how.